# Continous Movement and Gravity Switch With 1 button

Tags: unity, c#, movement

I have a sphere with a rigidbody on it, and it moves to the right continously as I need it, but as it moves I want the space bar to be able to switch the gravity (so it either rides on the ceiling or on the floor), as it moves along to the right.

Please help, have been googling consistently for the past 3 hours.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float movementSpeed = 10;
    private bool haspressed;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && haspressed == true) {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            haspressed = false;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space") && haspressed == false) {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            haspressed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.Now just need to figure out how to use only one key for this action.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class gravity : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float ychange = 5;
void Update () {
{
    if(Input.GetKey ("space")){

        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0f,ychange,0f);}

}
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0f,-ychange,0f);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `bool` variable to track your script's `isGravityInverted` state? Then you can toggle that state when `GetKeyDown` returns true.

Comment: Ended up just putting each key press in its own method so I could also call it to a button click and handle touch input in IOS, it worked great.